# How to set ignore null fields globally (JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)

Tags: json, serialization

i need to return an object fro mController in .NET core app 7.0

the object returned with `null` fields which I don't want to:

```
{
    "field_1": "value",
    "field_2": null,
    "field_3": null
}
```

I wish to see

```
{
    "field_1": "value"
}
```

I found out what i can add an attribute  `[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]` to every filed and it will solve the problem, but i have hundreds of objects and dozens of fields in each of them.

Is it possible to set that property globally?
Somewhere like:

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions... ???
});
```

I'm not using newstonsoft anymore, please help if you know how to use System.Text.Json.Serialization

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

ok, i removed line:

```
//builder.Services.AddControllersWithJsonOptions();
```

and added a new one

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(j =>
{
    j.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});
```

which solved "ignore null properties" problem